# Cancel task.delay without exception or use exception to control flow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm unsure about two possibilities to react to an event in my code. Mostly I'm concerned about which one needs less resources.
I have a method with an observer registered to an `eventproducer`. If the `eventproducer` returns something, the method exits and the caller of the method starts the method again (you can think of it as a kind of a long polling).

The `eventproducer` sometimes fires lots of events per seconds and sometimes rests for minutes.

The first approach was to await a delay of 500ms and then check if there is something to return or otherwise (until a timeout of 5 minutes) again delay for 500ms.

```
eventProducer.RegisterListener((events)=>{evList.Add(events)});
while(evList.Count=0 && !TimeOut){
    await Task.Delay(500);}
eventProducer.UnRegister(...);
// return evList, method gets recalled immediately
```

The second approach was to use a `CancellationToken`. If the `eventproducer` produces something, the `CancellationTokenSource` cancels the source. And in the method I wait for `Task.Delay(5min, cancellationToken)`.

```
eventProducer.RegisterListener((events)=>{evList.Add(events);
                                          cancelSource.Cancel();}
try
{
     await Task.Delay(5min, cancellationToken)
}
catch(TaskCanceledException){//nothing to do};
eventProducer.UnRegister(...);
// return evList, method gets recalled immediately
```

The advantages of the second approach are that the method immediately returns if the producer produces something and that we don't have to await and awake in a loop.

But with the second approach every time the producer produces something, a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown. I'm concerned that this could affect system load more than the awake and await every 500ms especially i times when the `eventproducer` produces lots of events.

Am I overestimating the cost of throwing and catching an exception? And is there a way to cancel `Task.Delay` with a `CancellationToken` but without throwing a `TaskCanceledException`? I.E. something like `task.setComplete`?

Comment: it was just a placeholder for "a longer time"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want an immediate notification similar to what a cancellation gives you but without an exception you can simply use `TaskCompletionSource`.

`TaskCompletionSource` is how you create a promise task. You get an uncompleted task from the `Task` property and you complete it (or cancel) with `SetResult`. You can use it to actually pass on the result itself:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Events>();
eventProducer.RegisterListener(events => tcs.SetResult(events));

var result = await tcs.Task;
eventProducer.UnRegister(...);
```

This solution doesn't have any exceptions and doesn't use unnecessary polling

---

To answer your specific questions:

> Am I overestimating the cost of throwing and catching an exception?

Probably. You need to test and prove it's really an issue.

> And is there a way to cancel Task.Delay with a `CancellationToken` but without throwing a `TaskCanceledException`?

Yes. Add an empty continuation:

```
var delayTask = Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
var continuationTask = delayTask.ContinueWith(task => { });
await continuationTask;
```

Comment: thanks, TaskCompletionSource looks exactly like what i was looking for!

Comment: When using "await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task => { });", Why does it no longer throw the task cancelled exception? 

Before i had a try-catch for this, does the framework still need to process catch and handle the exception internally, or does it not throw an exception in the first place with this?

Comment: @Snellface the `Task.Delay` task is still cancelled, and if you await it it will still throw an exception. But you're not awaiting it.. you're awaiting a continuation that does nothing. Since it does nothing and doesn't have a CancellationToken it can't throw any exceptions.

Comment: @i3arnon so it would probably, in a very small way, be more efficient to use a TaskCompletionSource instead? The first time i heard of it was in this QA so i am fairly unfamiliar with this. IMO it's more semantically to cancel a delay rather then have it complete early, however if the cost of cancellation is much greater then the cost completion the semantic difference is negligible in this specific situation. I might also be wrong in thinking that the task has to handle the exception internally, but that is how i understand it, it's just that when i don't await i don't need to catch it,right?

Comment: @Snellface There's actually no exception in this case.. but for something other than `Task.Delay` there might be. Awaiting a canceled task throws an exception, but you don't need an exception to create a canceled task. Imagine the `Task.Delay` method returns a TaskCompletionSource and instead of calling `tcs.SetResult` it uses `tcs.SetCanceled`. That way the `delayTask` is canceled and awaiting it will throw an exception without the task catching any exception itself.

Comment: Another option for Task.Deplay `await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(ConfigureAwaitOptions.SuppressThrowing | ConfigureAwaitOptions.ContinueOnCapturedContext)` that helps me. This is in .NET 8. Tested in MAUI button clicked event handler.