# How to wait for a thread is finished before execute next code?

Tags: c#, async-await

I need a code like this:

```
module.StopAndWait();
module.DoSmth();
module.Resume();
```

I've written class AsyncModel. I have a problem with line "while (!isStopped);". On this line, the program freezes. I think isStopped must be changed but it doesn't.
I've tried to declare isStopped as volatile.
But anyway program has problem on "while (!isStopped);".

```
public class AsyncModel
{
    bool run = false;
    bool isStopped;
    public async void Run()
    {
        if (run) return;
        await Task.Run(() => progr());
    }
    public void StopAndWait()
    {
        run = false;
        while (!isStopped) ;// <-- Problem
    }
    void progr()
    {
        isStopped = false;
        run = true;

        while (run)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }

        isStopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you use async methods you want parallelism otherwise use sync methods .

Comment: assign a t or f to isstopped

Comment: I am not abel to recreate the described behavior [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZE9b8IwEIbn5FdcmeyBQIdOKZVQlw5FqgoSQ9XBxAdYdezI54AQ4rendhJQGPB253uf9z4KGhfWYVOTMjtYnshjmafDKFvtHQoZEtlK0B89@s1TI0qkShQIKyQP56aqN1oVUGhBBHM6mWJhJer0nCYbazW42sAMtkIT5n1K0dLbqkIZEr1cRCEcrJLwXRvG0yToE7UFFvQcHPramVCeiKNQHmKTWSxkHGZvUDm7c4zzUHC5IVtYNJobuQ6iK/S@oeS4VxqBPd2a4pBPJvA6HsOXsxuNZQttab1P39xVMKR1cO/qITuOEKIoSrpVZkuNWLHnl@k0Nh0N7ngdAMIbDERe@OtcC6EMI@/CTX5@QbgdcYj8g3BQWlkH2xkYPA4uwlqn7rPdXRu/W0M2JNZOefxUBtnoQ2htR8Pquy0@UK2t03LUneDSXJp/ "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: `volatile bool isStopped;`, try that, and the same with the `run` field. It is a bad idea to create your own threading signals, there are good classes in .NET for this already, look into ManualResetEvent/AutoResetEvent, and ideally you should probably be using tasks fully, with CancellationToken, etc. What does `resume` look like?

Comment: There are multiple problems (eg the use of `async void` and race conditions due to the use of variables without synchronization). The main problem is that nothing calls `Run` so `StopAndWait` never finishes. If you want to wait for a task to terminate, use `await`. All of this code could be replaced with a single `await Task.Run(()=>progr())`. If you wanted to do something before awaiting, `var myTask=Task.Run(...); Something(); await myTask;`.

Comment: The proper way to signal cancellation is to use a CancellationTokenSource and pass a CancellationToken to `progr`. Check [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this code is trying to run a loop that can be cancelled in the background. 
The easy way to do this is by using a CancellationTokenSource and a CancellationToken, eg :

```
void progr(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Do something expensive
    }
}
```

Notice that `progr` has no reference to external fields. All it needs is that `token`.

The CancellationTokenSource should be created before the task itself starts.

```
Task thatTask;
CancellationTokenSource cts;

public void StartTheJob()
{
    cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
    thatTask=Task.Run(()=>progr(cts.Token));
}
```

To stop the task, all that's needed is a call to `cts.Cancel()`

```
public async Task StopTheJob()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    //Wait for the cancelled task to exit
    await thatTask;
}
```

To add a delay, use `await Task.Delay(...)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(). [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) can be cancelled and doesn't block the threadpool thread used to run the task :

```
async Task progr(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Do something expensive
        await Task.Delay(1000,token);
    }
}
```

Check [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) for more

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000, token);` This may raise a `TaskCanceledException` that should be caught and handled.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I know. One could add a lot more code to this, if one knows what its actual purpose is. One could use a *timer* to execute a recurrent job instead of that loop. The question though asked (indirectly) how to properly cancel a background task. If someone asked how to poll in the background, a better idea would be a timer or something similar instead of a loop

Comment: I thought it would be an interesting question to ask, but has already been asked: [Cancel task.delay without exception or use exception to control flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739788/cancel-task-delay-without-exception-or-use-exception-to-control-flow)

Comment: I would like to know why does `run = false;` affect to `while(run)...` but `isStopped = true;` doesn't affect to `while (!isStopped) ;` ?

Comment: @RomanAleshin any attempt to modify global state from another thread needs synchronization to avoid random results but in this case `async void` is an additional serious problem - `async void` is only meant for event handlers. It means the method is a `fire-and-forget` method that can't be awaited and the task may be garbage collected before it completes. There's not even any guarantee that the task *will* start before the application exits. The line `isStopped = true;` may not run at all. Use `async Task` instead and store the task in a variable or field at least

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem could easily be solved by using the plain old synchronous code.  Also,  try to use `Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.  Lastly, consistency in your method naming.